# SAPUI5 Fiori Create an Extendable Fiori Application

Tags: sapui5

I've created a custom SAPUI5 Fiori application and I need to provide extendability to my custom application.

I've seen many posts about creating extension applications for Fiori Standard applications

What is the procedure to convert my custom application to an extendable application? And how to create an extension app for my custom app.

And what are the facts that I need to consider when creating the custom application to allow extending it?

Comment: You can create an Extension App in the Web IDE for SAP UI5, see here: https://blogs.sap.com/2015/03/03/extend-a-fiori-application-with-sap-web-ide-part-1/

Comment: @NathanielFlick thanks.. what I need is to extend my own custom application using an extension app

Comment: I try to understand the issue: You have developed your own custom app, deliver it to several “customers” of yours, who are going to apply some specific individual modifications each on their own ? You want to achieve extensions similar to what is described in this document using [Extension Points](https://archive.sap.com/documents/docs/DOC-52555) and [UI controller hooks](https://archive.sap.com/kmuuid2/80ec8772-9b7b-3110-6999-f0f326fedf00/Use%20Cases%20for%20Extending%20the%20UI%20of%20SAP%20Fiori%20Apps.pdf).

Comment: @SAPFioriCrew exactly